# Making calls in background?

Tags: android, methods, screen

I want my application to call out from the phone. I already have it so that it will call out using ACTION_CALL. It brings up the the screen that makes the call. I want to know how to over ride that screen so when it calls out instead of showing that the application goes straight to the home screen, or even shows that screen for a split second or so then goes to the home screen.

Comment: hmm.. interesting. virus programming ahh!! :-) . Can I ask why you want a call without user knowledge? Usually for call you need to answer and use should have control. SMS is different.

Comment: Its call forwarding. forwards call to a diffrent phone it shows its calling just in the background

Comment: If you make an outgoing call, then you're making a call from the phone. It's not possible to somehow receive an incoming call and then redirect it to an outgoing call via your phone at the same time as the incoming call is happening. All that will happen is you disconnect the incoming call and then the first phone calls the second phone. If I want to use call forwarding I let my provider handle that. The only way you could do it (possibly) is with VoIP such as Skype and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it isn't possible to do this (and I really hope there isn't a way to do it).

What would stop a malicious app from making calls that would cost the owner of the phone huge amounts of money?

Comment: I am not sure of the whole justification. There are applications that can trap and/or send sms. This could also be used as a trojan in the phone. Same with data usage. Most applications use data with no justification (if no other justification works, they could justify it as requirement for goodle analytics). So there are so many ways users could owe huge amounts of money. Whether a phone call is possible.. I dought.. just because a phone call is ALWAYS a 2 way communication and hence requires user interaction. (Except for Call forwarding).

Comment: @GSree: You are right that SMS and data usage can also be abused. I don't think much about that as my phone contract gives me free unlimited SMS messages and I only enable 'mobile internet' access manually. When connected with wi-fi I have no data costs. Obviously they can be used for other malicious actions (even if there is no charge to the user) but malicious calling of 'premium' numbers would quickly incur $$$$. Call forwarding is handled by my provider - I can set it from my phone but, when set, the calls are forwarded by my provider and never reach my phone...the way it should be.